# スプレッドシートからGASを使って「送信日時を設定」でメール送信したい

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

スプレッドシートからGASを使ってメール送信を作成中です。
普通にメールを送る分には出来ましたが、これをGmailの機能にある「送信日時を設定」で送りたいと思います。
調べてもスクリプトエディタのタイマー機能を使ってシートに記載された時間になったらメール送信、のようなものしか見付けられなかったのですが、そうではなく、Gメールの「送信日時を設定」と同じ挙動(Gmailの「予定」フォルダに格納され時間になったら送信される)にしたいのです。
可能かどうかも含め、もしご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらご享受いただければと思います。
よろしくお願い致します。